# I need to get time with hours and minutes

Tags: php, html, laravel

I have this code:

```html
<input type="datetime-local" class="form-control" name="date" value={{$date}} readonly >
```

`$date` is with hours and minutes but it just give me an empty time whenever I use it.

I tried with `type="datetime"` and it gives me the time without `hh:mm`, how can I get it all?

---

**EDIT**: It worked, `$date` must be `timestamp` in the database and the input type must be of type `datetime`

Comment: can you show the output ?

Comment: When you say 'get' what do you mean?

Comment: @Snapey
I mean in my website project the output is dd/mm/yyyy --:--

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you surround the date value with quotes and provide it in ISO format:

```html
<input type="datetime-local" class="form-control" name="date" value="{{$date}}" readonly>
```

Your `$date` should be in the format `2022-07-31T15:35` for instance. Note the `T` in the middle.

Comment: sadly it gave the same with quotes
is the problem from the $date variable?

Comment: Yes its a problem if it s not in the right format.  Open the browser source page and look at the generated HTML to check what was passed

Comment: How can I make $date in this format 2022-07-31T15:35 ?
I mean what is the date type should I put in the table in DB

Comment: It worked as you said $date must be timestamp() in DB not datetime()
Thank you <3

Comment: date can be date time, but you should cast it to Carbon object and then format it in the blade file.